# Target Based commit point while updating into table

Tags: sql, updates, performance-testing, informatica

One of my mappings is running for a really long time (2 hours).From the session log i can see the statment "Time out based commit poin" which is tking most of the time and Busy percentage for the SQL tranfsormation is very high(which is taking time,I ran the SQL query manually in DB,its working fine ).So, basically there is a router which splits the record between insert and update.And the update stream is taking long.It has a SQL transforamtion,Update statrtergy and aggregator.I added an sorter before aggregator but no luck.

Also changed comit interval ,Lins Sequential Buffer lenght and Maximum memory allowed by checking some of the other blogs.Could you please help me with this.

Comment: Please investigate update performance. Run an update statement and check the run and execution plan. Are you having a lot of indexes on the table perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to avoid the transformations which are creating cache because in future if the input records increase. Cache size will also increase and decrease the throughput

1) Aggregator : Try to use the Aggregation in SQL override itself

2) Sorter : Try to do the same in the SQL Override itself

Generally SQL transformation is slow for huge data loads, because for each input record an SQL session is invoked and a connection is established to database and the row is fetched. Say for example there are 1 million records, 1 million SQL sessions are initiated in the backend and the database is called.

What the SQL transformation doing ? Is it just generating a Surrogate key or its fetching a value from a table based on derived value from the stream

For fetching a value from a table based on derived value from the stream:
Try to use lookup

For generating Surrogate key, Use Oracle Sequence instead

Let me know if its purpose is any thing other than that

Also do the below checks

Sort the session log on thread and just make a note of start and end times of 
the following

1) lookup caches creation (time between Query issued --> First row returned --> Cache creation completed)

2) Reader thread first row return time

Regards,

Raj

Comment: Using SQL instead of PowerCenter transformations (for aggregation or sorting) as a general rule is a bad idea. The whole reason to use ETL tool is to put less effort on database side. There can be some exceptions of course, like using DB sort in case an index is available.